# Why does location access fail in PyQt5 QWebenginePage when i want to display user geolocation on openstreetmap?

Tags: python, pyqt5, openstreetmap, qtwebengine

I'm loading openstreetmap in a PyQt5 webenginePage but i can't display user position on the map although i'm get user permission via a messagebox.

```
question = questionForFeature.get(feature)
if question:
    question = question.format(feature=securityOrigin.host())
    if QMessageBox.question(self.view().window(), title, question) == QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.setFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, QWebEnginePage.PermissionGrantedByUser)
    else:
        self.setFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, QWebEnginePage.PermissionDeniedByUser)
```

Nothing happens on the map, just this message displays in console:
serialnmea: No serial ports found
Location access failed.

My OS is windows 10 but my users may have older version of windows.

Comment: If you want the geolocation of Qt in windows as indicated by [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-index.html) you must have a GPS receiver: *Windows (with GPS receivers exposed as a serial port providing NMEA sentences)*, that is to buy and connect a GPS device.

Comment: How does the browser found out my location without gps device? Is there a way to use browser data?

Comment: Your browser uses other services that use your internet connection (IP) to track your position but unfortunately Qt does not use it in the case of Windows, but instead uses Linux as a backend to geoclue which is a SW that does provide the position. Exactly your goal is to obtain the position using the openstreetmap map or do you just want to obtain the position?

Comment: I want user to be able to specify a position near himself on the map, finding his position can help himself to specify desired position easily.

Comment: Provide a [MRE] and maybe I can provide a workaround

Comment: I have html and JS file that works properly on browser and this is what functioanality i want, How can i send this file to you?

Comment: publish the content of the files in the question

Comment: i have a folder with some image and html file that have almost 700KB size, Please see in this link (thanks alot) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSn8HPTpp13weHpqz4oH0gntHnMkBz73/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see that you are using "http://ip-api.com/json" to get the current position. Why don't you use it to continue setting the position of the marker

Comment: Because ip-api is very Imprecise and i use this to find user city.

Comment: How do you measure accuracy and why do you assume that Qt will give you a better position?

Comment: I thought it's possible to find position more accurate like as browser, ip-api accuracy is more than 5km in my test.

Comment: 5 Km is an acceptable precision if you are going to use the IP, I think you could get more precision looking for some other paid service or as Qt points out using a GPS

Comment: Which type of paid service you meant?

Comment: There are similar services to ip-api, it's just a matter of doing a search on the internet

Comment: Ok thanks for reply dear eyllansec